# Android app: read data then send to database : check if data matches

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I would like to ask You general question: i have android app[RFID ..]. Step 1: Read Step 2: need to send Read[red] data to Database if data matches, Matched! message.
Please give some advice which java classes to use: i have already experienced: Insert[post], Read, Delete, Update. But to check matching Read[red] data, i am facing problems. If you know some related links[only java], please provide here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android implements **SQLite** (not MySql) natively.

These are your options:

1. [Save data using SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)
2. [Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Answer (score 1):

Android recommends using Room for saving data locally.
[Room link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/room-sqlite-beginner-tutorial-2e725e47bfab)